# Executing the particle command in a specific dimension?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to execute the command:

```
/particle largesmoke 200 200 200 0 0 0 0.05 30
```

It works perfectly fine in the main world, but nothing happens in the nether. Is there a way I can specify which dimension the particle effect should be appearing in?

The executor of the command is the Console (using Skript's Execute Console Command ability)

Comment: Have you tried executing the command from the nether?

Comment: Yes, it works fine in the nether. However, the actual console itself is the executor of the commands (using Skript and the "execute console command" command). I should probably update my post to reflect that.

Comment: I'm wondering if it might be possible to trigger a command block located in the nether that will run the command.

Comment: needs to be done from console though, not a command block.

Comment: Why? I'm not saying you need to completely abandon using Skript, but right now you're painting yourself into a corner.

Comment: The particle effects work as a response to a player interaction that can happen at any time. They're not centered on the player but use an offset from it.  I'm not sure how to do that with command blocks.

Comment: What you want to do is completely doable with command blocks.  I always suggest that people focus on their actual problem (getting the particle effect to work in the nether) rather than the perceived solution (using Skript to do it).  Maybe you should be asking about how you can detect when a player performs the action you're looking for with command blocks.

Comment: I guess you're right. I'll just need to rework a few thousand lines of skript code into command blocks now though. Thanks.

Comment: You probably don't. If it's just a few things in the nether, then you can leave most of the overworld stuff alone.  In any case, a bunch of it is probably one to one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a possible workaround might be to execute off of an entity in the nether.

something like this *could* work, granted there is a zombie pigman somewhere in the loaded nether (and not in the overworld...)

```
/execute @e[type=zombie_pigman,c=1] ~ ~ ~ /particle largesmoke 200 200 200 0 0 0 0.05 30
```

a more reliable way would be, to use multiple commands in quick succession to test whether or not there is a player in the nether and then execute off of them:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a add inNether {Dimension:-1}
/execute @a[tag=inNether,c=1] ~ ~ ~ /particle largesmoke 200 200 200 0 0 0 0.05 30
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=inNether] remove inNether
```

all of those commands can be run in this order from the console and they should work just fine.